# Twitch API - Top Games for Past Dates

Tags: api-design, twitch

Good day. I have a running cron job that executes a script to get the the top games with views periodically (as documented here https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/games). However, the said cron job encountered a technical issue and stopped leaving a gap in my records. Is there a way to get the top games for the dates (stored hourly in my case) that my cron job missed or any function that is close to what I need? Thank you very much.